# What is the trick to determining what your /dev/mmcblk0p* is going to be when booting?

Tags: emulation, qemu

I'm trying to restore a backup made using [this tutorial](http://sysmatt.blogspot.com/2014/08/backup-restore-customize-and-clone-your.html) from a live Raspberry PI (with Noobs) to an external SD Card.

From there I made an image of the card on my linux box,

```
 sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=~/vm/rpBackup.img bs=1M
```

I booted with `sd.img` which I found in [this other tutorial](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/working-with-raspian-vms-in-qemu-in-ubuntu-14-04-x64.373224/) and also attached the image using this command:

```
$ sudo qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda sd.img  -hdb rpBackup.img
```

Once it was booted I mounted the vfat partition as well as the ext4 partition from the backup image, and changed them in accordance with the documentation in the [first tutorial](http://sysmatt.blogspot.com/2014/08/backup-restore-customize-and-clone-your.html):

## /mnt/r/etc/fstab

> (NOOBs Users: If you are running a SD card created with NOOBs, you
>   will need to manually modify the boot/cmdline.txt and etc/fstab files
>   on your new SD card before you can boot.
>
> You must edit and substitute
>   the mmcblk0p* device names for the proper ones. In the fstab, slash
>   (/) should be /dev/mmcblk0p and /boot should be /dev/mmcblk0p1.

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p   /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, so no using swapon|off from here on, use   
dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

## /mnt/boot/cmdline.txt

> In the
>   cmdline.txt file, root= part should be root=/dev/mmcblk0p2. Once you
>   have done that the OS that you backed up will be the only OS on the
>   new SD card event if your NOOBs SD had multiple flavors of raspberry
>   pi OS installed. My scripts on github discussed in the next section
>   handle all of this automatically, which makes things a bit easier.)

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait
```

Next, I tried to boot from the backup image in the emulator by running the following command

```
$ sudo qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=5000 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda rpBackup.img
```

and it stops here:

[image: An ILL Signal Killed the process]

I'm not entirely certain what the correct numbers are for the `/dev/mmcblk0p*` entries.  How do I find out what they are so that I can boot my image in qemu?

## Update

I finally got the machine to boot in qemu using the following command (from [this](http://xecdesign.com/qemu-emulating-raspberry-pi-the-easy-way/) tutorial):

```
sudo qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=100 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" -hda ./rpBackup.img
```

I think the source of the issue was that no init parameter was specified in the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> In the fstab, slash (/) should be /dev/mmcblk0p and /boot should be /dev/mmcblk0p1.

Contains a typo.  `/` is the **root** filesystem and it should correspond to this:

> In the cmdline.txt file, root= part should be root=/dev/mmcblk0p2.

I.e., in fstab `/` should be `/dev/mmcblk0p2`.

I'm not sure this explains your problem with QEMU, however.

Comment: `Contains a typo. / is the root filesystem and it should correspond to this:`

What should it correspond to?